# How to remove salesforce standard '' action'' fuctionality?

Tags: visualforce, action

I want to remove action header along with edit and delete ,how can i remove it .it is displaying after creating the records. and my users should not see that action facet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot remove the standard action functionality. Please vote for this idea.

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000ksRdAAI

Answer (score 1):

You would need to modify the edit/delete permission on the object in the profile or use a VF page to over ride it.

Taken from: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008ozHIAQ